# Getting error - "FeatureCollection (Error) User memory limit exceeded."

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, land-classification

I am facing the following error on Google Earth Engine (GEE) -"FeatureCollection (Error) User memory limit exceeded" while trying to perform a Level 2 Land Use Land Cover Classification (LULCC).

My study area is very big (about 15,000 sq km.), and I'm using Sentinel-2 data at a 10m spatial resolution. The feature collection (for which I am getting an error) acts as the training samples consists of 20 points. Ideally (if this error did not occur) I would like to expand this to 100-150 points.

After researching this error message, I realize that GEE restricts analysis space, therefore, I have tried to turn off the display of all layers but to no avail.

I am contemplating a few options now -

- clipping the study area into 20 peices and running LULCC for each piece individually. In my opinion this is far from ideal and I *guess* might get disparities.

I am also trying to achieve the same goal in ArcGIS Pro, but that's taking very long as well.

Another alternative I am pursuing is to upload the whole Sentinel-2 imagery as an asset on GEE.

Which solution would you use or do you have any additional suggestions?

P.S. I am very new to GEE.

Below is a sample of my code.

```
// Loadingimage collection and cloud mask
    var s2Sr = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED');
    var s2Clouds = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY');
    //#var degree2radian = 0.01745;
    
    //Filters
    var START_DATE = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
    var END_DATE = ee.Date('2023-04-08');
    var MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY = 65;
    
    //
    //Removing clouds
    function maskClouds(img) {
      var clouds = ee.Image(img.get('cloud_mask')).select('probability');
      var isNotCloud = clouds.lt(MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY);
      return img.updateMask(isNotCloud);
    }
    
    // The masks for the 10m bands sometimes do not exclude bad data at
    // scene edges, so we apply masks from the 20m and 60m bands as well.
    // Example asset that needs this operation:
    // COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY/20190301T000239_20190301T000238_T55GDP
    function maskEdges(s2_img) {
      return s2_img.updateMask(
          s2_img.select('B8A').mask().updateMask(s2_img.select('B9').mask()));
    }
    
    // Filter input collections by desired data range and region.
    var criteria = ee.Filter.and(
        ee.Filter.bounds(AOI), ee.Filter.date(START_DATE, END_DATE));
    s2Sr = s2Sr.filter(criteria).map(maskEdges);
    s2Clouds = s2Clouds.filter(criteria);
    
    // Join S2 SR with cloud probability dataset to add cloud mask.
    var s2SrWithCloudMask = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_mask').apply({
      primary: s2Sr,
      secondary: s2Clouds,
      condition:
          ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
    });
    
    //Mediaining and displaying cloud-free image
    var s2CloudMasked =
        ee.ImageCollection(s2SrWithCloudMask).map(maskClouds).median();
    var rgbVis = {min: 0, max: 3000, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
    
    //Map.addLayer(
    //    s2CloudMasked, rgbVis, 'S2 SR masked at ' + MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY + '%',
    //    true)
      
      
    //Clipping to AOI
    var MaskedClippedImage = s2CloudMasked.clip(AOI, 'MaskedClippedImage')
    
    
    Map.addLayer(
       MaskedClippedImage, rgbVis, 'SAImage')
    
    print(MaskedClippedImage)
    
    //1 = Water; 2 = Forest; 3 = ONE; 4 = RiverBank; 5 = Agriculture; 6 = Urban ; 7 = Snow
    
    var training = Water.merge(Forest).merge(ONE).merge(RiverBank).merge(Agriculture).merge(BuiltUp).merge(Snow)
    
    var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8']
    var train_image = MaskedClippedImage.select(bands).sampleRegions({
      collection: training,
      properties: ['Class'],
      scale: 10
    
    })
    
    print(train_image)
    //train classifier
    var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
      features: train_image,
      classProperty: 'Class',
      inputProperties: bands,
    })
    //run classification
    var classified = MaskedClippedImage.select(bands).classify(classifier)
    
    Map.centerObject(training, 11)
    var landcoverPalette = ['#030ed6', '#05e61b', '#c8ff09', '#00ffff','#c29400','#ff0000','#ff81f8']
    Map.addLayer(classified, {palette: landcoverPalette, min: 0, max: 8}, 'Classification')
```

Comment: For large jobs you should use the batch environment (See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments)  Your goal is to create export tasks (See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting).